# Importing project to eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

i have created my project in the c drive in a folder named DIW.
The folder has all the class file and source files.Now i want to import the entire project to eclipse and run it there,how should i do it?
I have searched on google for the same but did not get exact results,i hope to get some help from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse -> import -> General -> existing project into workspace

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse -> import select `FileSystem` and your source

OR

Eclipse -> Create New Project -> `Create from Existing Source`

OR

If you have maven type mvn eclipse:eclipse , then import to Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

File--> Import-->General-->Existing Projects into workspace